# Finding Duplicates with the data of three sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I have data in column A of three sheets.  I have to take one sheet's data and have to compare with the remaining two sheets' data.

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Your question is very vague. Please give us more details. What kind of data do you want to compare? Give us a short but practical example, if possible. A nice comparing/matching function is the `range.find` method in vba. Look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Without more context/information, I can only give you a high-level response but hopefully it can get you started.

To check if items in one range are found in another range, the code below builds a string from one range then uses "Instr" to compare each item from another range against it.  To do more sophisticated comparisons, I'd build arrays from the ranges.

```
Sub CompareLists()
Dim rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range
Dim cell As Range
Dim tmp As String

Set rng1 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A6")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A6")

'Build pipe-delimited string from cells in range
For Each cell In rng1
    tmp = tmp & cell & "|"
Next cell

'Remove last pipe
tmp = Left(tmp, Len(tmp) - 1)

'Loop list 2 and compare against list 1.
'Specifically, see if each item in list 2 is found in list 1
For Each cell In rng2
    If InStr(1, tmp, cell) > 0 Then

        'Print items from list 2 that are found in list 1
        Debug.Print "Found: " & cell.Value

    Else

        'Print items from list 2 that are NOT found in list 1
        Debug.Print "NOT Found: " & cell.Value

    End If

Next cell

Set rng1 = Nothing
Set rng2 = Nothing
Set cell = Nothing
```

End Sub